# Loading .browser file dynamically in a non-ASP.net website applications

Tags: asp.net, httpbrowsercapabilities

I have an offline process that needs to do some analysis on User-Agent strings, that are logged from requests on our production machines, the problem is I need to use the .browser file that has the required filters to parse & recognize the browsers from user-agent, and the only way to use the file that I know, is through having an ASP.net website and placing the .browser file under APP_Browsers folder, but given the nature of the offline process I can't have it in a website and I find the need to construct a HttpWebRequest object for each record to read the HttpBrowserCapabilities over killing.
So is there any other way to consume the .browser file and read the HttpWebBrowserCapabilities matching the user-agent.

Note: I found a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831352/httpbrowsercapabilities-custom-browser-file-parsing) similar question that is about 2 years old, that didn't get enough traction, so I thought may be things changed since then.